What can I replace manual SA key generation with?
We started using Google Cloud a year back. We used SA keys for several applications and for purpose of security, we renewed the SA keys every 30 days. This was okay when our environment was small but as the number of apps grew, it turned into a real pain (nightmare actually).
Is there an alternative to this ? Curious to know how other companies are doing this.
[ Should point out that majority of the apps are on Google Compute VM's, few are on Cloud Functions, GKE, Dataflow ]

If you're running on Google Cloud compute services then you shouldn't be generating Service Account keys as the credentials can be provided by the Metadata services (see Application Default Credentials). If you're running off-GCP then consider Workload Identity Federation. As a non-programming (architecture|ops) question, this question would be better addressed elsewhere.

@DazWilkin is 100% right! Could be a great answer!

@DazWilkin for better visibility to the community members I have posted the above statement as community wiki, please feel free to add data required

As DazWilkin suggested it is not a good practice to use Service Account keys for your application from a security standpoint. To add further based on the type of application and the domain under it gets classified there are already certain benchmarks which are widely used across the globe, for example CIS(Center for Internet Security), PCI DSS(Payment Card Industry Data Security Standard), ISO and GDPR(General Data Protection Regulation) etc..
Each of these standards mentioned above has their own set of regulations(some might be common), so try to implement that particular standards based on the domain under which your application is classified. If you want to go with a generic one as per this google official documentation first pen down what are the components you are using and what type of authentication mechanism can be used to access these components.
Adding the Information provided by DizWilkin

If you're running on Google Cloud compute services then you shouldn't
be generating Service Account keys as the credentials can be provided
by the Metadata services (see Application Default Credentials). If
you're running off-GCP then consider Workload Identity Federation.

Note: Always make sure that you are trying to use the least possible privilege for accessing your application and its infrastructure so that it won’t breach completely when an incident happens.
